# jinja2: get first item in list whether list exists or not

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

For the first line below, the jinja2 template renders whether `x` exists or not. However, in the second line, the template only renders if `x` is an existing list. If it isn't I get an error (assume if `x` exists it is always a list with at least one item):

```
<p>x: {{ x }}</p>

<p>x[0]: {{ x[0] }}</p>
UndefinedError: 'x' is undefined
```

Is there a better way to check if a variable exists and get its first item than what I have here (I have tons of instances of `x` which have much longer names in my template and I'd rather not wrap it with the if clause every time):

```
{% if x %}
  <p>x[0]: {{ x[0] }}</p>
{% endif %
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jinja supports inline `if else` statements, and unlike Python also allows omitting the `else`.

```
{{ x[0] if x }}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved by both this approach

```
{{ x[0] }}
```

or--

```
{{ x|first }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try returning a list of lists and iterating over it, that way you only write the "variable check" once.

Something along these lines:

```
{% for x in list %}
    {% if x %}
        <p>x[0]: {{ x[0] }}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```